# JQUERY + Update HTML Code with Variable

Tags: jquery

Below is code that sits in an iframe.

I'm able to get the variable 'url' from the parent document and can see it in the alert.

I need to be able to update the 'http://www.domainname.com' text in the fb:like-box.

What is the best way to do this?

thx

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
   var url = $('div#facebookURL', window.parent.document).text();
   alert(url);
 });
 </script>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <fb:like-box href="http://www.domainname.com" width="237" height="498" show_faces="true"      stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some id to your like box, like:

```
<fb:like-box id="fbLikeBox" href="http://www.domainname.com" width="237" height="498" show_faces="true"      stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>
//then
$("#fbLikeBox").attr("href", url);
```

Hope it helps